# Bind textbox user input from datagrid cells

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a pretty simple CRUD app which displays data from a database in a datagrid. This works fine. I'd like to have a comment column in the datagrid, where each row has a textbox that the user can insert a comment into. The problem is, the property in the class displaying data doesn't get updated with the comment. 
I can use a simple DataGridTextColumn with IsReadonly="False" for that column. This actually gets the comments, but it look horrible, and the user has to double-click the cell to enter it. With a textbox, validation looks smoother and the user only has to click once to enter it, but here the binding doesn't work. I've tried different variantions of DataGridTemplateColumn but I can't seem to get it right or find a working example. 
What am I missing?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" Width="120" IsReadOnly="False">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserComment}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox IsEnabled="true" Text="{Binding Path=UserComment}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code for the TextBox and also the viewmodel code for the comment property?

Comment: Try setting UpdateSourceTrigger property of the binding to 'PropertyChanged'. Otherwise it will be updated only upon lost focus.

Comment: I have implemented INotifypropertychanged in my ViewModel,  and am using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay in my binding. I just accidentally deleted them when I posted the question and renamed the Comment property to English. Sorry about that. I have a save button in my View so all data shown is saved to a database. When I click that button I get all the data from the View, except the comments. Those are not updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel, don't forget to notify property changed after updating the value.
Else the view does not know it has to sync.

[An elegant way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://www.wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html)

A basic way would be:

```
private string _userComment;

public string UserComment
{
   get { return _userComment; }
   set 
   {
      _userComment = value;
      PropertyChanged("UserComment");
   }
}

private void PropertyChanged(string prop)
{
   if( PropertyChanged != null )
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop);
   }
}
```